# Stability and Equilibrium ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on this problem: NOTE u is an element of the reals

dx/dt = (x-1)(x-u^2+1) = F(x)

I want to find the equilibrium points and stability:

So I put F(x) = 0 and got the equilibrium points:

x = 1 and x = u^2-1

Next I check the stability:

F(x) = (x-1)(x-u^2+1)

F'(x) = 2x-u^2

So for x=1;
F'(1) = 2-u^2

And for x=u^2-1; 
F'(u^2-1) = u^2 - 2

Am I correct in saying these are both >0 and so are unstable?

Comment: How can $2-u^2$ and $u^2-2$ be both $>0$?

Comment: Okay yes I see. So they must bothe be <0 since u is an element of the reals and are stable ? @JuliánAguirre

Comment: They have different sign , unless $u=\pm\sqrt2$.